# Recurrence relation of L'Hôpital's rules

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Today I woke up with this thought. Imagine I have a limit that is given by:

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} {[f(x)/g(x)]}$$

If $f(x_0)=g(x_0)=0$ then I can solve it using L'Hôpital's rule. If $f'(x_0) = g'(x_0)=0$, then I should perform another derivation and keep doing that many times as I need. Imagine that after $n$ L'Hôpital derivations I get:

$${[f^{(n)}(x)/g^{(n)}(x)]=\alpha[f(x)/g(x)]}.$$

Does that necessarily means that the limit does not exist in $x=x_0$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that to apply L'Hôpital's rule we need

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=0$$

(not necessarly $f(x_0)=g(x_0)=0$ as indicated) and similarly for the derivatives.

Let consider for example $f(x)=g(x)=e^{-x}$ such that

$$\forall n\quad{[f^{(n)}(x)/g^{(n)}(x)]=\alpha[f(x)/g(x)]}$$

with

$$\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{e^{-x}}{e^{-x}}=1$$

Therefore the answer is no it doesn't.

Comment: That's not a valid example since you can't apply L'Hopital's rule at all. Edit: it's not valid because we require $x \to x_0$ for some real number. But I guess if you let $x$ be infinity it works, so I withdraw my objection.

Comment: @marksaving Sorry, isn't it in the form $0/0$?

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider the function $f(x) = g(x) = x^2$ around $x = 0$. Then we have $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.